# Should I `#include` statements within `main(){}`?

Tags: c++, c++11, include

I'm working on a CFD solver. An existing CFD solver that I've used a fair amount is OpenFOAM. OpenFOAM routinely, within it's solvers, has things like:

```
...
int main ()
{
    ...
    // Simplified version, but similar effect
    double time = 0.0;
    double endTime = 10.0;
    while (time < endTime)
    {
        ...
        #include "fileThatSolvesForVelocity.H"
        #include "fileThatSolvesForPressure.H"
        ...
        time += deltaT;
    }
}
```

Here, the files that are included aren't really 'headers' in the usual sense, since they just contain statements to be copied into `main()`. However, since they're run repeatedly (perhaps even repeatedly within one loop) this reduces code-duplication, and also compartmentalizes sections in reasonably obviously named 'header' files.

IDEs typically don't like this style of inclusion - they have no idea where all the variables in the 'header' come from, and can't provide any meaningful interpretation of things.

Is this style 'bad', or just a convenient use of C++ `include` mechanisms?
In particular, should I attempt to avoid it, perhaps through use of classed objects for each field? Is there a better way to do this (C++11 and Boost are both available, if needed)?

Comment: *"Is this style 'bad'"* Yes, *very* yes. It's awful, and you should absolutely avoid it. Define functions or classes inside your header files, include the headers at the *top* of your file, and then use the classes/functions inside your loop.

Comment: _"IDEs typically don't like this style of inclusion"_ - neither do other programmers. Functions also reduce code duplication, use them.

Comment: Whether it's *bad* is subjective, but this technique is how [X Macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) are done.  I'm not sure why you're doing it though.  You could remove code duplication with more clarity by using functions or C++11 lambdas.

Comment: I've done this kind of thing, even though I'm not a big proponent, at namespace scope, to initialize huge static arrays. You put all the initializers into some file, and then `#include` that after the array declarator. In that case, it seems like the lesser of two evils, the other evil being littering your source file with hundreds of lines of array initializers. My recommendation is to not do it, especially for the use case you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not convention.

I am not sure what you want to achieve here. For the compiler/linker it is not an issue; at compile-time all included files are combined into one in the precompile stages i.e. absolutely no gain in performance or so, probably the opposite.

You can put all of your variables in a class or in a namespace if you're looking to group them in some way. You can use `#region` in the IDE if you want to increase readability and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is bad! Use of #include for anything other than normal headers is generally a bad idea.

If you really want to duplicate the code in place use a macro, but it is generally better to extract a function, or possibly even a class with several member functions.

Performance wise, inline functions have little or no overhead as the compiler will very likely skip the function call unless the code is too complex, and just generate the code in place. If performance is a problem, profile before and after any optimisation attempt.